# Grid item height not matching responsive square child

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I'm creating a web application with React and Material-ui. I need a responsive square div for a map component, however, using [a trick from iamsteve.me](https://iamsteve.me/blog/entry/how-to-flexible-squares-with-css) breaks the grid layout as the parent Grid div does not expand.

I have tried moving the class which is square to the grid element, but this doesn't help.

```
map: {
    height: '100%', width: '100%', position: 'absolute'
},
mapContainer: {
    height: '0',
    paddingBottom: '100%',
    position: 'relative'
},
```

```html
<Grid item>
  <div className={classes.mapContainer}>
    <Paper className={classes.map}>
    // map
    </Paper>
  </div>
</Grid>
```

[image: Screenshot]

The height of the Grid item does not match the size of the square. This is an issue for items that follow.

Answer (score 0):

For `responsive` square, you should use [Grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#fluid-grids) provided by `Material-UI`.

A simple change in your code to use `Grid` could be this

```
<Grid container justify={"center"}>
   <Grid item xs={6}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>Your Map Here</Paper>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

To constrain the width of the containing element, you can do

```
root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    height: "50vh",
    width: "50vh"
  },
```

I have updated a Codesandbox demonstrating it at https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-pjssu

I hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't force the contents of the Grid item to be a square, which is what I require here.

Comment: I updated the codesandbox and the link. Once you fit in your map, you should see it with in the constraints, give it a try. If not, fork this sandbox, add the map, and share it

Comment: I can't add it to the sandbox since the map element is Google-Map-React and this introduces cross origin issues. However, I have simulated the map with a div. The size of the div is not square (you can't see it). https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-59t49?fontsize=14

Comment: I tried again, but the CORS issue is hitting me up at https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-fgnse. Do you have a `apiKey` that you could share privately and delete once the problem is resolved?

Comment: You don't need to use a Google Map since it acts the same as a div with height 100% and width 100%. Thanks for helping btw.